# basemap ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

gives

```
ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I installed basemap with conda

```
wayne@dors:~$ conda install basemap
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I am running ubuntu 15.04, Python3.4, matplotlib 2.1.1, numpy 1.8.2
How do I fix?

Comment: I find Home/matplotlib/lib/mpl_toolkits but there is no module named basemap.

Comment: `Home/matplotlib/lib/mpl_toolkits` is an unusual place for the fike to be - I'd expect `.../site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap.pth` or similar

Comment: @WayneAngel did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 10):

Try to install it with this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

"Only the 'crude' and  'low', resolution datasets are installed by default" .You may need to install the following for high resolution:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install from source, not via `conda`, as per the docs :

https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

Comment: OK.  I tried installing from source per above.  The install appeared to go OK.  I still get the same  error.  I did notice that the "python setup.py install" wrote to "/home/wayne/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/basemap-1.1.0-py3.6.egg-info."  This seems odd to me but, since I have a $PATH to this I expect it to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

try install basemap from source

```
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```