# Matplotlib ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, macos-catalina, matplotlib-basemap

I was trying to create a plot of a map with `matplotlib`, and I tried to run this code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap()
plt.show()
```

but I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I have read many answers to similar problems, but none of them have worked for me.

([Python basemap module impossible to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import), [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356192/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mpl-toolkits-basemap))

I am running Python 3.7 on macOS 10.15.5 using PyCharm

Comment: I presume you have, but just to be sure, have you tried the instructions from the main site? (https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html)

Comment: @JoshuaFooJF yes, I followed those instructions but still get the same error.