# Basemap is not getting installed

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot a map using Basemap. When I run

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I tried to do

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

but still getting the same no module thing as before, I did try the things from this post [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356192/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mpl-toolkits-basemap) but still no results

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and try this -

```
python -m pip install basemap
```

If working on a notebook, try using -

```
!python -m pip install basemap
```

Refer to https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap#installation for more installationrelated support.

Comment: It worked but I had to open it with administrator permision

Comment: is this mean we can still use Basemap? I thought they depreciated in favor of Cartopy. I love Basemap more, to be honest.