# No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, macos-catalina, matplotlib-basemap

When I run this code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
map = Basemap()
plt.show()
```

It gives me an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

I tried following the instructions at [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html), but it still gives me the same error.

Any other questions I have read having this same issue have not been helpful, I still get the same error. I have also posted this question before but did not get any helpful answers.

I am running Python 3.7 on macOS 10.15.5 using PyCharm CE

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388217/basemap-importerror-no-module-named-mpl-toolkits-basemap) might help. You need to install before you import. Conda helps manage dependencies.

Comment: I kind of suspect that the PyCharm CE python interpreter you are running is not the same as the interpreter when you install the package. There is a certain possibility.

Comment: @ParthShah I ran `conda install -c conda-forge basemap`, it said it was installing basemap, geos, and some other modules, and everything went well. I still got the same error when I ran the code.

Answer (score -3):

You have to install `mpl_toolkits`

By

```
pip install mpl_ toolkits
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and got this error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpl_toolkits (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mpl_toolkits`